# getting striping error in rdf/xml

Tags: rdf

i am studying about how to write RDF and XML and I create my own RDF/XML, but I get an error about striping. What should I do solve to this problem?

```xml
  <foaf:products>
    <foaf:type>
        <foaf:nameid>L814</foaf:nameid>
        <foaf:size>32-34x30</foaf:size>
        <foaf:color>
        <colorid id="001">White</colorid>
            <colorid id="002">Red</colorid>
            <colorid id="003">Blue</colorid>
            <colorid id="004">Black</colorid>
        </foaf:color>
        <foaf:price>170 Baht</foaf:price>   

        <foaf:nameid>L814</foaf:nameid>
        <foaf:size>32-34 x 30</foaf:size>
        <foaf:color about="White,Red,Blue,Black">
            <colorid id="001">White</colorid>
            <colorid id="002">Red</colorid>
            <colorid id="003">Blue</colorid>
            <colorid id="004">Black</colorid>
        </foaf:color>
        <foaf:price>170 Baht</foaf:price>   

        <foaf:nameid>L811</foaf:nameid>
        <foaf:size>32-34 x 30</foaf:size>
        <foaf:color about="White,Red,Blue,Yellow,Pink">
            <colorid id="001">White</colorid>
            <colorid id="002">Red</colorid>
            <colorid id="003">Blue</colorid>
            <colorid id="004">Yellow</colorid>
            <colorid id="005">Pink</colorid>
        </foaf:color>
        <foaf:price>170 Baht</foaf:price>   


    </foaf:type>
</foaf:products>
```

Comment: I don't see any error here.  Please include the error message that you're getting (and where it's coming from, &c.).  The XML that you're showing here isn't a complete RDF/XML document either, so we can't, for instance, test it in an RDF/XML validator.  As per the guidelines: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself," and you should "Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions, and something that I hope will answer your question.

#### Don't try to write RDF/XML by hand.

Don't write RDF/XML by hand, or even try to write it programmatically, if you don't have to.  There are much easier RDF serializations to write, such as Turtle, and there are plenty of tools that can convert between the different serializations for you.

#### If you do write it by hand, know the specification inside and out

If you *are* going to try to write RDF/XML manually, do have a close read through the [RDF/XML Syntax Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-rdf-syntax/#section-Syntax-node-property-elements), because it's a complicated specification, and there are lots of edges cases that are tricky to get right.

#### About this particular problem

When you write RDF/XML, there should be a root `rdf:RDF` element.  The children of that element represent RDF resources that are the subject of triples.  These may be `rdf:Description` elements or, if they have an `rdf:type`, the element name can be the `rdf:type`.  The elements inside those have property IRIs as their element names.  Those property elements can have children, in which case the children are the object of the property.  E.g., you should end up with something like the following.  This is described in [Section 2.2 Node Elements and Property Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-rdf-syntax/#section-Syntax-node-property-elements) of the spec.

```xml
<rdf:RDF>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about=".../thing1">
    <dataProperty>some literal value</dataProperty>
    <objectProperty>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=".../thing2">
      </rdf:Description>
    </objectProperty>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about=".../car788"> <!-- something of type Car -->
    <rdf:type rdf:resource=".../Car">
    …
  </rdf:Description>
  <ex:Car rdf:about=".../car789">          <!-- something else of type Car -->
    …
  </ex:Car>
</rdf:RDF>
```

The XML that you've shown doesn't match this kind of structure.